# TA/USB battery charging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

Apologize if the question seems silly, searched for the answers on google but couldn't get an answer, so please manage to help.
I am studying detailed charging process of a smartphone battery,(software and hardware also). need to know in detail how the usb charging and TA charging works. would be grateful if anyone can explain. 
In Li-ion "TA/USB Battery charging", what does "TA" signifies?
Is there any difference between charging using wall adapter and USB charging except the amount of charging current?if yes, what is that?

Also i asked question related to battery charging on Physics and stackoverflow, they recommended StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the question belongs to the forum as its more towards the consumer electronics side. Anyways TA means Terminal-Adapter. And yes there is a big difference between charging through a wall adapter and through the USB.

In order to charge fast, we need to provide the charge at a faster rate, aka more current to be provided at the source.

A USB does not have a large current output and thus charges the phone slowly, whereas a wall adapter can provide large amounts of current which charges the batteries faster.

Comment: thanks. Is this the only Difference i.e. amount of charging Current? Isn't there any another??

Comment: In terms of charging speeds. Yes thats the only difference.

Comment: ok. what are in 'other' terms?

Comment: Well , by others I just mean the normal differences, that the adapter converts AC in to DC, but the USB provides direct DC. The current output cannot be high. etc